# Bug report tools android with e-mail sending

Tags: android, remote-debugging

Hello i need bug report tools for android which allow me to send reports from app to e-mail.
Send me please tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

[Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/), [Bugsense](https://www.bugsense.com/) and [Bugsnag](https://bugsnag.com/) are some of the many (on top of my head at the moment) crash/bug reporting tools that are available for android.